# Ubuntu 16: pip3 installs to Python2 instead of Python3

Tags: python, dependencies, distributions, pip

Having issues linking pip to python 3.7. Both pip and pip3 been installed but linking to Python 2.7.

I have tried to reinstall Python3 and then pip, but no progress.

I get the following message:

Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.

This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source

```
$ python --version
Python 3.7.4

$ pip -V
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
  warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)
pip 19.2.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)

$ pip3 -V
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/__init__.py:83: RequestsDependencyWarning: Old version of cryptography ([1, 2, 3]) may cause slowdown.
  warnings.warn(warning, RequestsDependencyWarning)
pip 19.2.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)


$ sudo apt-get install python3-pip
[sudo] password for TarikDev: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package python3-pip is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'python3-pip' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: Why do you have a Python in `/usr/local`?

Comment: @muru because python.  and python teaches contempt for operating systems and OS packaging tools.

Comment: @cas What do you mean, exactly?

Comment: If you have python 3 then you must have pip as module. What will become if you try 'python -m install pip --upgrade' ?